# How to make a window have taskbar text but no title bar

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

How can I make my window not have a title bar but appear in the task bar with some descriptive text?
If you set the Form's .Text property then .net gives it a title bar, which I don't want.

```
        this.ControlBox = false;
        this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog;
        this.MaximizeBox = false;
        this.MinimizeBox = false;
        this.ShowInTaskbar = true;
        this.Text = "My title for task bar";
```

I've found a partial solution, to override CreateParams:

```
    protected override System.Windows.Forms.CreateParams CreateParams
    {
        get
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
            cp.Style &= ~0x00C00000; // WS_CAPTION
            return cp;
        }
    }
```

However this causes my window to be resized as if they have a title bar, ie it's taller than it should be.  Is there any good solution to this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One approach to look into might be to set the `FormBorderStyle` property of your `Form` to `None` (instead of `FixedDialog`).

The drawback to this approach is that you lose the borders of your window as well as the Titlebar.  A result of this is that you lose the form repositioning/resizing logic that you normally get "for free" with Windows Forms; you would need to deal with this by implementing your own form move/resize logic in the form's MouseDown and MouseMove event handlers.

I would also be interested to hear about better solutions.

Answer (score 8):

In my case I have a Form with `FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.SizableToolWindow` and the following `CreateParams` override did the trick (i.e. I now have a form without caption and without additional margin for the title, but it keeps the title in the task bar):

```
protected override System.Windows.Forms.CreateParams CreateParams
{
    get
    {
        var parms = base.CreateParams;
        parms.Style &= ~0x00C00000; // remove WS_CAPTION
        parms.Style |= 0x00040000;  // include WS_SIZEBOX
        return parms;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just set the border style to None.

```
this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
```

Answer (score 2):

Once you have removed the borders with the FormBorderStyle, as mentioned already, you can make it draggable fairly easily. I describe this at http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/DraggableBorderless.aspx.

Comment: Nice and example, but in the real world, but there are often more considerations with dragging the form, for instance, we don't want to drag if the mouse is over a control or between controls, or want to resize if it's close to borders.

Comment: Absolutely. You need to capture that also, testing how close you are to the form boundary, changing the mouse pointer, getting the preferred border size from Windows, etc.  A bit too much for one example though - perhaps I'll create another.