# Remove title bar text of a window but keep status bar text

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am working with Windows Forms, is it possible to create a window which has text in the status bar, but has no text in the title bar at the top of the application? (Largely because the standard title text which prints on my Aero glass I have implemented looks terrible as it's too high and I am drawing my own text title and obviously don't want the double up).

This solution ([How to make a window have taskbar text but no title bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198233/how-to-make-a-window-have-taskbar-text-but-no-title-bar)) is not satisfactory as I still wish to keep a `FixedDialog` window frame.

Thanks for your help all.

** **I am aware of John's recommendation, but still seeking clearer direction, anybody feel free to put forward your ideas** **

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This should do it:

```
[DllImport("uxtheme.dll")]
public static extern int SetWindowThemeAttribute(IntPtr hWnd, WindowThemeAttributeType wtype, ref WTA_OPTIONS attributes, uint size);

public enum WindowThemeAttributeType : uint
{
    /// <summary>Non-client area window attributes will be set.</summary>
    WTA_NONCLIENT = 1,
}

public struct WTA_OPTIONS
{
    public uint Flags;
    public uint Mask;
}
public static uint WTNCA_NODRAWCAPTION = 0x00000001;
public static uint WTNCA_NODRAWICON = 0x00000002;

WTA_OPTIONS wta = new WTA_OPTIONS() { Flags = WTNCA_NODRAWCAPTION | WTNCA_NODRAWICON, Mask = WTNCA_NODRAWCAPTION | WTNCA_NODRAWICON };

SetWindowThemeAttribute(this.Handle, WindowThemeAttributeType.WTA_NONCLIENT, ref wta, (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(WTA_OPTIONS)));
```

Comment: Nm.  With help from this article (http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vista/HideCaptionIcon.aspx) I setup the references I needed.  Cheers! This has been a big help.

Comment: Pinvoke.net is also a big help figuring out these interop structures and stuff.

Answer (score -1):

What you are talking about would require subclassing to get into the guts of the application. Esentially you would be skinning your form by intercepting certain messages (like WM_PAINT etc.). It's not a simple thing to do if you've never worked at that level before.

Comment: Well I'm already knee deep in invoking unmanaged libraries with the DWM API. So I'm happy to hear all solutions.

Comment: Here is an introduction in case you haven't touched Subclassing or development in the deep internals of Windows: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815775