# C# taskbar name

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make a window have taskbar text but no title bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198233/how-to-make-a-window-have-taskbar-text-but-no-title-bar)

I am using a sizeable window style with no name and a false control box setting to achieve this look

[image: image from url]

But because it has no name, old versions of windows like xp wont know the name of the application. How can I keep this style of window, and keep the window name.

Comment: Even a C or C++ method would do, I can convert it after.

Comment: What are you using? WinForms or WPF?

Comment: Greg - a code sample would useful, also can you use the SO image uploader. Your link is liable to suffer from link rot leaving the question no longer useful for future users of the site. Otherwise this question is likely to be closed by other users. Thanks.